# Interface naming convention?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I have created an interface `RequestCreation` :

```
public interface RequestCreation {

    public Request createRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest);
}
```

I have one implementing class uptill now: `RequestCreationBean`.

Is the naming of the interface appropriate ??

Comment: I might use something like `RequestCreationImpl` ... it really depends on whether calling it a bean is appropriate.

Comment: I'd probably call it `RequestCreator`, but this question is entirely opinion-based,

Comment: I would like to use I in front of class name. IRequestCreationBean

Comment: I would use IRequestCreation as the interface name

Comment: 4 comments and 4 different opinions. Is this helping?

Comment: Be consistent in what ever you choose

Comment: Please review [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask) (this is covered by the latter).

Comment: I think putting `I` at the front of interface names is standard practice for C#.  My impression is that most Java programmers consider it kind of _gauche_.

Comment: The informal convention used to be that interface names should be adjectives, for example Cloneable, Closeable, Serializable, Iterable, ... but it doesn't apply throughout the JDK by any means.